# How to multiply variables of a netcdf file with different constants using NCO or CDO?

Tags: constants, netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have a netCDF file containing different variables (val1, val2, val3). The names of the variables are indicated, in fact, they are completely different from each other.
I want to multiply the variables with different constants such as:

```
val1*c1 
val2*c2 
val3*c3
```

How I could do that with `NCO` or `CDO`?

Comment: note that "cdo" is not the tag for climate data operators (that was already taken unfortunately) so you need to tag with "cdo-climate" - I corrected it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NCO as decribed [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2):

```
ncap2 -s 'val1*=c1;val2*=c2;val3*=c3' in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 3):

In `cdo` you can use `expr` in a similar way to nco on each variable.

```
cdo expr,'val1=val1*c1;val2=val2*c2;val3=val3*c3' in.nc out.nc
```

see section 2.7.1 of the cdo manual 1.9.9 for more details.